# Is it possible in Gulp to use a string to start with instead of a source file?

Tags: string, sass, gulp

Normally when I use Gulp I start with:

```
gulp.src('some/file.txt).pipe( ... ) // etc
```

Can I also use a string instead of a file? For example:

```
gulp.str('some text').pipe( .... ) // etc
```

The use case I'm working on is that I'm creating a SCSS string ad-hoc and want to pipe it to the libsass. But I don't want to have create a temporary file but use a raw string instead. Example:

```
var myString = 'html { color: red; }';
gulp.str(myString).pipe(sass()) // etc
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "Have you tried it yet?". I tried all kind of stuff. The `gulp.str()` is pure a hypothetical method to support my question. What I've come up with so far is trying to use the `data` and `outFile` options of gulp-sass / node-sass, but so far with no luck:

    `return gulp.src('./foo.txt', {read: false})
        .pipe(sass({data: 'html { color: red; }', outFile: 'test.css'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));`

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure from the example code if that was a real method of not.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
var file = require('gulp-file');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  var str = 'Some string value that you want to pipe';

  return file('tmp.js', str, { src: true }) // The file name can be anything
    ... // <- Piping contents of str here
    .pipe(gulp.dest('xxx'));
});
```

Comment: This worked out great for me-- the gulp-file plug-in being used can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file).